# Do I need to use という in 「この話が事実に基づいているという証拠はある。」?

Tags: grammar

> この話{はなし}が事{じ}実{じつ}に基{もと}づいている**という**証{しょう}拠{こ}はある。
>
> *There is evidence that this story is based on facts.*

Does the meaning change if I remove という so it becomes as follows?

> この話{はなし}が事{じ}実{じつ}に基{もと}づいている証{しょう}拠{こ}はある。

Comment: I feel "という" in this instance sort of has the feel of English quotes, meaning it sets apart the phrase in a meta sense. I feel like removing it still allows it to be understood, but possibly less natural. Would be curious to hear a native speaker's opinion on this, though.

Comment: When a phrase like この話が事実に基づいている modifies a noun, you usually have to figure out the relationship between the noun and the phrase by context. Sometimes the noun is the subject of the phrase, sometimes an object, etc. Is it possible that という here can provide some kind of hint about the relationship between この話が事実に基づいている and 証拠? Or can という be used regardless of the kind of relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1)「この話が事実に基づいている**という**証拠はある。」
>
> 2)「この話が事実に基づいている証拠はある。」

1) feels just wholesome and complete.  It is something people would actually say and write in real life and it enters my Japanese-speaking brain without any constraint whatsoever.  Just like Matsuzaka beef, I never have to chew it to swallow.

2), however, does not feel as natural as 1).  I would not necessarily call it incorrect or ungrammatical, but I wonder how many people actually would say or write it.

It is not that the "meaning" will change if you remove 「という」.  It is just that one would need to spend a minute thinking of an "appropriate" situation where one might say 2).

One situation where one might say 2) would be when the phrase 「事実に基づいている**という**証拠」 has already been uttered at least once or twice in a conversation and then, the same or another person repeats the phrase without 「という」 to make it shorter.

When you have to stop and think hard of a situation where a phrase could be used naturally, you are usually dealing with a not-so-natural phrase to use independently in the first place.

Comment: I would actually use 2), because I really can't see a reason why I would need という in a normal modifying clause. Could you explain to me why　という is more natural (or even needed) in this phrase?

Answer (score 2):

1)「この話が事実に基づいているという証拠はある」

2)「この話が事実に基づいている証拠はある」

If I were asked which way of the above two statements I would use when I’m demanding the evidence of a story to somebody, I would more likely use the former.

It is felt to me the first one is saying “I have the evidence that verifies the story is based on the fact,” and the second one is saying “This story is based on the fact. I have the evidence.”

The difference is that the word, ‘という’ in the quote 1) links the fact that ’話が事実に基づいている’ with '証拠,’ while ‘話が事実に基づいている’ in the quote 2) functions as a modifying clause of 証拠.

Likewise we can say either way;

1) 彼の会社が倒産したという話を聞いた – I heard a rumor that his company has bankrupted.

2) 彼の会社が倒産した話を聞いた - I heard a rumor - his company has bankrupted.

1)彼が結婚するという話は本当かい？- Is it true that he is going to marry?

２)彼が結婚する話、本当かい？- He is going to marry. Is that story true?

I’m not sure I was able to reflect the difference of the nuance of “with and without という” exactly, nor
I don’t say 2) is grammatically incorrect either, but am positive that 1) sounds smoother, and more natural than 2), which sounds like something lacking to me.